# Linq to SQL using ITable instead of Table

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have inherited some old code which use Linq To SQL. In DataContext I need to use ITable interface instead of Table. I have changed generated linq data context in this way:

```
public System.Data.Linq.ITable<XYZ> SomeEntities
{
   get
   {
       return this.GetTable<XYZ>();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately after the change I getting many exceptions about properties of entities like:

System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Property 'Int64 SiteId' is not defined for type 'System.Data.Linq.ITable`1[XYZ]'
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression expression, MemberInfo member)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.AccessMember(SqlMember m, SqlExpression expo)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitMember(SqlMember m)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression expr)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitBinaryOperator(SqlBinary bo)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression expr)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitIncludeScope(SqlIncludeScope scope)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Bind(SqlNode node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType,     SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Compile(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.ExecuteQuery(DataContext context, Object[] args)
       at System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Invoke[TArg0,TArg1,TResult](TArg0 arg0, TArg1 arg1)
       at ...

Int64 SiteId property is part of XYZ class.

UPDATE:

Problem appears when LINQ query is compiled by CompiledQuery.Compile.

Comment: ...so change it back and think of a better plan.

Comment: Why do you need the interface only? If you're worried about the type, you can add a constraint.

Comment: I want to create interface for datacontext to make possible to mock it. That's why I need to use ITable.